Python - Adobe InDesign Javascript Scripting Help to Call JSX from Python
I'm trying to call Adobe InDesign JSX file from a python, below is the sample code:
I wanted to run this on Adobe InDesign 2024 or higher version. I saw some samples on Python InDesign scripting: Get overflowing textbox from preflight for automatic resizing
as reference which may work on Adobe InDesign CS 6, but I need to work on Adobe InDesign 2024 Creative Cloud.
<pre>
<code>
import win32com.client

def create_indesign_document_with_text():
    try:
        # Initialize COM
        print("Initializing COM...")
        app = win32com.client.Dispatch('InDesign.Application')

        # Create a new InDesign document
        print("Creating a new InDesign document...")
        doc = app.Documents.Add()

        # Define the text content
        text_content = ("This is a sample text with some bold and italic words. "
                        "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. " * 5)
        # Define text attributes
        bold_text = "This is bold text."
        italic_text = "This is italic text."

        # Create a text frame
        print("Adding a text frame with sample content...")
        page = doc.Pages.Item(1)
        text_frame = page.TextFrames.Add()
        text_frame.GeometricBounds = ["12.7mm", "12.7mm", "287mm", "200mm"]  # Adjust the bounds as needed

        # Add the main text content
        text_frame.Contents = text_content

        # Apply formatting to parts of the text
        # Note: InDesign uses 0-based index for characters
        text_range = text_frame.Characters
        text_range.Item(0).ChangeTextPreferences.appliedFont = app.Fonts.Item("Arial")
        text_range.Item(0).ChangeTextPreferences.fontStyle = "Bold"
        text_range.Item(0).ChangeTextPreferences.pointSize = 12

        # Apply bold formatting to a specific range
        bold_start = text_content.find(bold_text)
        bold_end = bold_start + len(bold_text)
        text_range.ItemByRange(bold_start, bold_end - 1).ChangeTextPreferences.fontStyle = "Bold"

        # Apply italic formatting to a specific range
        italic_start = text_content.find(italic_text)
        italic_end = italic_start + len(italic_text)
        text_range.ItemByRange(italic_start, italic_end - 1).ChangeTextPreferences.fontStyle = "Italic"

        # Save the InDesign document
        save_path = r'INDESIGN_FILE_PATH'
        print(f"Saving the InDesign document to {save_path}...")
        doc.Save(save_path)

        # Call the JSX script
        jsx_script_path = r'JSX_FILE_PATH'
        print(f"Executing JSX script: {jsx_script_path}...")
        app.DoScript(jsx_script_path, 1246973031)  # Use ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT

        print("Document created and script executed successfully.")

        # Close the document
        print("Closing the InDesign document without saving changes...")
        doc.Close(1)  # 1 means save changes

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_indesign_document_with_text()
</code>
</pre>

While running the above code, I'm getting the below error :
<pre>
<code>
Initializing COM...
Creating a new InDesign document...
Adding a text frame with sample content...
An error occurred: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.',
 (30475, 'INDESIGN EXE PATH',  'The requested member of the collection does not exist.', None, 0, 0), None)
</code></pre>

Can you help me?

The error happens before the javascript is called. Why do you think this is a javascript issue?

Thanks for the hint and help. I would debug line by line.

# Note: InDesign uses 0-based index for characters. It looks like InDesign uses 1-base index.

Try to change the lines:
text_range.Item(0).ChangeTextPreferences.appliedFont = app.Fonts.Item("Arial")
text_range.Item(0).ChangeTextPreferences.fontStyle = "Bold"
text_range.Item(0).ChangeTextPreferences.pointSize = 12

with:
text_range.Item(1).appliedFont = app.Fonts.Item("Arial")
text_range.Item(1).fontStyle = "Bold"
text_range.Item(1).pointSize = 12

And replace the ItemByRange() (I'm not sure if this method works at all in this case):
text_range.ItemByRange(bold_start, bold_end - 1).ChangeTextPreferences.fontStyle = "Bold"

with the loop:
for i in range(bold_start+1, bold_end): 
    text_range.item(i).fontStyle = "Bold"

And do the same for 'italic':
for i in range(italic_start+1, italic_end): 
    text_range.item(i).fontStyle = "Italic"

